# Send all options from a select list to another JSP

Tags: html, forms, list, jsp

I currently have a JSP with a select that looks like this:

```
<select name="withoutAccess" size="5">

<c:foreach var="item" items="${obj.withoutAccess}">
    <option>${item}</option>
    </c:foreach>
</select>
```

For the sake of clarity, I'll only post the select list, as the rest works well.

Now, in my form, when I click the submit button, I want to catch all values in the select list in the other page.

I'm only managing to obtain the option that is selected in that list when I press the button.

How can I obtain the rest?

I've tried with request.getParameterValues("withoutAccess"), but it has only 1 option, the one that is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found one solution.

Create a javascript script that puts all options with selected = true, that way I can catch them in the request :)

Answer (score 1):

Only the selected options ever get sent in a form post. If you want to get the entire list of options, you need to look them up again (i.e., from the database), or store them in a persistent storage location such as session or application state.

Comment: But how can I keep saving the changes?